# Include logo in title page with KOMA-script

Tags: graphics, titles, koma-script

I would like to ask if there is an easy way how to include some graphics (logo) on the title page (I'm using `scrreprt` class from KOMA-script). Until now I've done it like this:

```
\title {
  \normalfont \normalsize \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/logo}
  \horrule{0.5pt}
  \huge ARIO project
  \horrule{2pt}
}
```

But I feel that this is not the right way. And I wasn't able to find any tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For the classes `scrreprt` and `scrbook` try using the environment `titlepage` (inside the document) instead of the command `\title`.

Comment: Thanks, but there is still not any command like "logo" for including graphics...

Comment: If you are willing to use the `\maketitle` command, you could just put it in `\titlehead{…}`. But it seems that you want finer control of the title page layout…

Answer (score 4):

I use the package [eso-pic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) in addittion to [graphicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) in order to put an image in a specific point of the title page, then in the `\titlepage` command or in the page where I want the logo I use the command:

```
\AddToShipoutPicture*
{%
\put(100,100)%the specific point of the page with coordinates (x=100, y=100)
 {\includegraphics[scale=2]{logo.jpg}}%
}
```

After a pair of tries with `\put(x,y)` you'll finally find the coordinates where you want your logo.

Edition:

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fix-cm}                             % big letters
\usepackage[scaled=.9]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{blindtext}
%----------------------------------------------- colors
\usepackage[pdftex,%                    
dvipdfm,%
dvipsnames,%
svgnames,%
usenames,%
table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{gris}{gray}{0.45}                  % gray
\definecolor{burgundy}{rgb}{0.5, 0.0, 0.13}     % burgundy

\addtokomafont{section}{\Large\sffamily\color{burgundy}}     % text color for Sections
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\large\sffamily\color{burgundy}}  % text color for Subsections
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\sffamily\color{burgundy}}     % text color for Subsubections

%----------------------------------------------- graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}


%----------------------------------------------- opening
\author{Joan Queralt Gil}
\newcommand{\version}{00}
\newcommand{\code}{Code}
\newcommand{\course}{Course}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------- Titlepage
\begin{titlepage}\sffamily

\raggedleft
\noindent
{\color{burgundy}
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
{\Huge\bfseries
MWE\\

Subtitle\\[3ex]

{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont Acronym}\\[2ex]
\course \\
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\noindent
}}%
\raggedright
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    %--- minipage
    \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}\large
        Code: \code\\
        Version: \version\\
        [3ex]
        {\color{gray}\small{Make sure this document is valid. Check out the website.}} \\
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vfill
\bigskip
%----- graphic
\AddToShipoutPicture*
{%
\put(100,100)%
{\includegraphics[scale=2]{logo.jpg}}
}

\end{titlepage}
%\maketitle

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

that produces:

[image: result]

Comment: Any full MWE(minimum working Exmaple) with any koma-script class, in the title

Comment: I've edited my entry with a complet MWE. Try it.