# logo on bottom of scrreprt title page

Tags: titles

Is there any way to add two logos, left and right, on the title page of a `scrreprt` report?

I cannot find a solution - so I am wondering if it is possible. I managed to get the logos on the top of the page (with errors, but working) using

```
\titlehead{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo.jpg}&\hfill&\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo.jpg}}
```

Comment: this may help: [Include logo in title page with KOMA-script](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220228/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `\titlehead`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mwe}% example images
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\titlehead{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{%
    \parbox[t][\dimexpr\textheight-\ht\strutbox\relax][b]{\textwidth}{%
      \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}\hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}%
  }}}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is loading `scrlayer` and defining a new layer that can be added to the pagestyle empty.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[% define a new layer
  foreground,
  textarea,
  contents={\parbox[b][\layerheight][b]{\layerwidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}\hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}%
  }}
]{titlepage.logos}


\usepackage{mwe}% example images
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{empty}{titlepage.logos}% add the layer to pagestyle empty
\maketitle
\RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{empty}{titlepage.logos}% remove the layer

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

---

Or you can position the logos in the footline

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[% define a new layer
  foreground,
  foot,
  contents={\parbox[b][\layerheight][b]{\layerwidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}\hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}%
  }}
]{titlepage.logos}


\usepackage{mwe}% example images
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{empty}{titlepage.logos}% add the layer to pagestyle empty
\maketitle
\RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{empty}{titlepage.logos}% remove the layer

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

If there are more than one title page it could be better to define a new pagestyle for the first titlepage

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[% define a new layer
  foreground,
  foot,
  contents={\parbox[b][\layerheight][b]{\layerwidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}\hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}%
  }}
]{titlepage.logos}

\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firsttitlepage}{titlepage.logos}% new pagestyle


\usepackage{mwe}% example images
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}
\titlehead{\thispagestyle{firsttitlepage}}% change the pagestyle for the first title page
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\publishers{Publishers}
\dedication{Dedication}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The foot line solution is exactly what I was looking for. However, it does add the logos on both the first (front page) and second page of the title pages.  How could this be restricted to just the front page?

Comment: How do you get a front page and a second title page?

Comment: The  scrreprt report splits the title page after \title{},
\subtitle{},
\author{},
\publishers{}, and adds the 
\dedication{} section onto the next page. So I get the logos on the first title page and the second one.

Comment: I have updated my answer.